# Bash, csv file: get number of rows by column name

Tags: bash, csv, count

What I have:

```
file.csv
car,    speed, gas, color
2cv,    120,   8  , green
vw,      80,      , yellow
Jaguar, 250,   15 , red
Benz,      ,      , silver
```

What I have found:

This script returns exactly what I need by column number:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F', *' -v col=3 '
FNR>1 {
   if ($col)
     maxc=FNR
}
END {
  print maxc
}
' file.csv

read -p "For End press Enter or Ctl + C"
```

I get exactly the output which I need (the number of the last line of column):

```
* for "col=1" ("car" column), the answer: 5
* for "col=2" ("speed" column), the answer: 4
* for "col=3" ("gas" column), the answer: 4
* for "col=4" ("color" column), the answer: 5
```

What I am looking for:

- I am looking for a way to get the same not by "vol=volumnumber p.e. vol=3" but by "vol=columnheadlinevalue p.e. vol=gas".

It can be, it need additional like:

```
col_name=gas # selected column headline
col=get column number from $col_name # not working part
```

Comment: What is expected output ?   
Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A couple of things to clarify in the question: (a) Are the column headers included in the count? (b) When will the number of rows will be different for different columns? In the example, it appears that 'car', 'speed', and 'color' all have a count of 4. In typical "CSV" files, it is common to consider every column in every row to be populated, even if it is populated with the empty string.

Comment: I have clearly revised my question, so that it now probably offers little scope for interpretations other than those I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do exactly what you do but which finds the column name when `FNR==1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

columns=(car speed gas color)

for col in "${columns[@]}"
do
    LINE_CNT=$(awk '-F[\t ]*,[\t ]*' -vcol=${col} '
    FNR==1 {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
            if($i == col) {
                col = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i>NF) {
            exit 1;
        }
    }
    FNR>1 {
        if($col) maxc=FNR;
    }
    END{
        print maxc;
    }' file.csv)

    echo "$col $LINE_CNT"
done
```

Output:

```
car 5
speed 4
gas 4
color 5
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217809/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-bash-csv-file-get-number-of-rows-by-column).